# How to use icons in ImageButton without it getting pixelated?

Tags: android, image-scaling, android-imagebutton

I am using ImageButton in my custom bottom navigation. And I have set icons of 32*32 size as src to them.

here is xml

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_profile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/btm_nav_user_act"
        android:text="Profile"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_nav_bg"
        android:textColor="#000"/>
```

When I view it on my phone they look pixelated. I'm fine them being smaller but I dont want them to be pixelated. How can I make adujustment so that they look sharper.

Here are the icons

[image]
[image]

Comment: You will need higher resolution images if you want to have them a reasonable size on high density screens.

Comment: Use vectordrawables

Comment: @Henry where can I find icons higher resolution of that width and height?

Comment: @migos where can I find vecotrdrawables?

Comment: @vikasdevde ask your designer for them (or do it yourself).

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html - in this link everything about vectordrawables should be explained in detail

Comment: @Henry I do not have designer. And I am not a designer. I am learning

Comment: Are those icons you're using vectors (SVGs)?

Comment: @Edric they are png

Comment: @migos absolutely what I wanted. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your image is very small to begin with, you have 2 options:

- Remove the hardcoded height (50dp), your original image may be smaller than this, forcing its height may be reducing its quality on certain devices.
- Have the same drawable you're using but for different phone densities. I'm guessing you only have one version of your drawable image in the drawable folder, on certain phones with certain densities, this image may display badly (just as it may be displayed just fine on certain other phones).

Answer (score 0):

Lets make custom Image Button with linear layout and imageview

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:src="@drawable/btm_nav_user_act"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Profile"
                android:textColor="#000"/>


        </LinearLayout>
```

Now use linear layout as a button.